# How to get myshopify URL from user for Shopify oAuth 2.0 when it forbidden to ask for it according to Shopify?

Tags: oauth-2.0, shopify

According to the new Shopify terms and conditions we cannot ask any user for their myshopify URL to authenticate our shopify app. Our app is still unlisted so we don't have the listing URL of our app either through which users can install our app for testing purposes.
Shopify apps still require a myshopify URL to continue the authentication process using oAuth 2.0. Any suggestions might help!

References:
https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-apps/why-is-it-prohibited-to-ask-for-shopify-url/td-p/962581

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you test the OAuth flow on a development store while you were developing your app? The app listing install link is basically the "App URL" field in your App setup with the query param `shop=<myshopify_domain>` added to it.

You can give the URL to the merchant who's doing the testing and have them fill out the query param themselves.